# Replace values in a dataframe based on lookup table

Tags: r, dataframe, lookup

I am having some trouble replacing values in a dataframe. I would like to replace values based on a separate table. Below is an example of what I am trying to do.

I have a table where every row is a customer and every column is an animal they purchased. Lets call this dataframe `table`.

```
> table
#       P1     P2     P3
# 1    cat lizard parrot
# 2 lizard parrot    cat
# 3 parrot    cat lizard
```

I also have a table that I will reference called `lookUp`.

```
> lookUp
#      pet   class
# 1    cat  mammal
# 2 lizard reptile
# 3 parrot    bird
```

What I want to do is create a new table called `new` with a function replaces all values in `table` with the `class` column in `lookUp`. I tried this myself using an `lapply` function, but I got the following warnings.

```
new <- as.data.frame(lapply(table, function(x) {
  gsub('.*', lookUp[match(x, lookUp$pet) ,2], x)}), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Warning messages:
1: In gsub(".*", lookUp[match(x, lookUp$pet), 2], x) :
  argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In gsub(".*", lookUp[match(x, lookUp$pet), 2], x) :
  argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In gsub(".*", lookUp[match(x, lookUp$pet), 2], x) :
  argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Should be able to do that with cbind on the two columns of row and column indices. See ?"["

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You posted an approach in your question which was not bad. Here's a smiliar approach:

```
new <- df  # create a copy of df
# using lapply, loop over columns and match values to the look up table. store in "new".
new[] <- lapply(df, function(x) look$class[match(x, look$pet)])
```

An alternative approach which will be faster is:

```
new <- df
new[] <- look$class[match(unlist(df), look$pet)]
```

Note that I use empty brackets (`[]`) in both cases to keep the structure of `new` as it was (a data.frame).

(I'm using `df` instead of `table` and `look` instead of `lookup` in my answer)

Comment: Why does this make all of the fields in `new` **except** those in the altered column disappear?

Comment: match produces NA's which I found as a problem: see this example  match(1:6,c(1,3,4,2,5))

Comment: @NicolasMolano You may use `na.omit()`.

Answer (score 28):

Another options is a combination of `tidyr` and `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
table %>%
   gather(key = "pet") %>%
   left_join(lookup, by = "pet") %>%
   spread(key = pet, value = class)
```

Comment: I get all NAs with this solution.  It must be my setup: 'table <- data.frame (P1 = c("cat", "lizard", "parrot"), 
                        P2 = c("lizard", "parrot", "cat"), 
                        P3 = c("parrot", "cat", "lizard"),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)'
'lookup <- data.frame (pet = c("cat", "lizard", "parrot"), 
                      class = c("mammal", "reptile", "bird"),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)'

Comment: I think an updated version of this solution would be something similar to: `table %>%
  gather(key = "pet") %>%
  left_join(lookup, by = "pet") %>%
  spread(key = pet, value = class)`
since gather and spread were replaced by pivot_longer and pivot_wider
https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/09/tidyr-1-0-0/

Answer (score 21):

Anytime you have two separate `data.frame`s and are trying to bring info from one to the other, the answer is to *merge*.

Everyone has their own favorite merge method in R. Mine is `data.table`.

Also, since you want to do this to many columns, it'll be faster to `melt` and `dcast` -- rather than loop over columns, apply it once to a reshaped table, then reshape again.

```
library(data.table)

#the row names will be our ID variable for melting
setDT(table, keep.rownames = TRUE) 
setDT(lookUp)

#now melt, merge, recast
# melting (reshape wide to long)
table[ , melt(.SD, id.vars = 'rn')     
       # merging
       ][lookup, new_value := i.class, on = c(value = 'pet') 
         #reform back to original shape
         ][ , dcast(.SD, rn ~ variable, value.var = 'new_value')]
#    rn      P1      P2      P3
# 1:  1  mammal reptile    bird
# 2:  2 reptile    bird  mammal
# 3:  3    bird  mammal reptile
```

---

In case you find the `dcast`/`melt` bit a bit intimidating, here's an approach that just loops over columns; `dcast`/`melt` is simply sidestepping the loop for this problem.

```
setDT(table) #don't need row names this time
setDT(lookUp)

sapply(names(table), #(or to whichever are the relevant columns)
       function(cc) table[lookUp, (cc) := #merge, replace
                            #need to pass a _named_ vector to 'on', so use setNames
                            i.class, on = setNames("pet", cc)])
```

Comment: I really like this approach and used it in an application, but was surprised by how the results were sorted (which is not evident in toy examples with fewer than 10 rows). It seems that because the rownames stored in `rn` are strings, they sort like stings, i.e., `'10'` precedes `'2'`, and the result is accordingly sorted. My ugly workaround is to add a final sorting step where I coerce `rn` to numeric and sort on that, but I wonder if there is a more canonical `data.table`-y way to handle this.

Comment: @DanielKessler data.tables don't keep rownames -- perhaps you want to cast `rn` to numeric before trying to merge? `table[ , rn := type.convert(rn)]` and then proceed to melt/merge/recast

Answer (score 13):

Make a named vector, and loop through every column and match, see:

```
# make lookup vector with names
lookUp1 <- setNames(as.character(lookUp$class), lookUp$pet)
lookUp1    
#      cat    lizard    parrot 
# "mammal" "reptile"    "bird" 

# match on names get values from lookup vector
res <- data.frame(lapply(df1, function(i) lookUp1[i]))
# reset rownames
rownames(res) <- NULL

# res
#        P1      P2      P3
# 1  mammal reptile    bird
# 2 reptile    bird  mammal
# 3    bird  mammal reptile
```

#### data

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
       P1     P2     P3
 1    cat lizard parrot
 2 lizard parrot    cat
 3 parrot    cat lizard", header = TRUE)

lookUp <- read.table(text = "
      pet   class
 1    cat  mammal
 2 lizard reptile
 3 parrot    bird", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Same idea implemented using `purrr` package, saving a few keystrokes: `res <- purrr::map_df(df1, ~ lookUp1[.x])`

Answer (score 4):

I did it using the `factor` built-in.

```
table$P1 <- factor(table$P1, levels=lookUp$pet, labels=lookUp$class)
table$P2 <- factor(table$P2, levels=lookUp$pet, labels=lookUp$class)
table$P3 <- factor(table$P3, levels=lookUp$pet, labels=lookUp$class)
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35636674/3549570) showing how to do this in dplyr doesn't answer the question, the table is filled with NAs. This worked, I would appreciate any comments showing a better way:

```
# Add a customer column so that we can put things back in the right order
table$customer = seq(nrow(table))
classTable <- table %>% 
    # put in long format, naming column filled with P1, P2, P3 "petCount"
    gather(key="petCount", value="pet", -customer) %>% 
    # add a new column based on the pet's class in data frame "lookup"
    left_join(lookup, by="pet") %>%
    # since you wanted to replace the values in "table" with their
    # "class", remove the pet column
    select(-pet) %>% 
    # put data back into wide format
    spread(key="petCount", value="class")
```

Note that it would likely be useful to keep the long table that contains the customer, the pet, the pet's species(?) and their class. This example simply adds an intermediary save to a variable:

```
table$customer = seq(nrow(table))
petClasses <- table %>% 
    gather(key="petCount", value="pet", -customer) %>% 
    left_join(lookup, by="pet")

custPetClasses <- petClasses %>%
    select(-pet) %>% 
    spread(key="petCount", value="class")
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried other approaches and they took a really long time with my very large dataset. I used the following instead:

```
    # make table "new" using ifelse. See data below to avoid re-typing it
    new <- ifelse(table1 =="cat", "mammal",
                        ifelse(table1 == "lizard", "reptile",
                               ifelse(table1 =="parrot", "bird", NA)))
```

This method requires you to write more text for your code, but the vectorization of `ifelse` makes it run faster. You have to decide, based on your data, if you want to spend more time writing code or waiting for your computer to run. If you want to make sure it worked (you didn't have any typos in your `iflese` commands), you can use `apply(new, 2, function(x) mean(is.na(x)))`.

*data*

```
    # create the data table
    table1 <- read.table(text = "
       P1     P2     P3
     1    cat lizard parrot
     2 lizard parrot    cat
     3 parrot    cat lizard", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Benchmark

Out of burning curiosity, I just ran a benchmark with some of the approaches that I want to share with you. I couldn't quite believe some of the statements about performance in the answers and am trying to clarify this herewith. In order not to be misled by different rows/columns ratios, I consider three scenarios:

1. ncol == nrow
2. ncol << nrow
3. ncol >> nrow.

It might be beneficial to coerce `as.matrix` beforehand, so I included this as an **additional solution** (*unlist_mat*).

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  lapply=Dat1[col_set] <- lapply(Dat1[col_set], function(x) Look$class[match(x, Look$pet)]),
  unlist=Dat2[col_set] <- Look$class[match(unlist(Dat2[col_set]), Look$pet)],
  unlist_mat=Mat[, col_set] <- Look$class[match(as.vector(Mat[, col_set]), Look$pet)],  ## added
  ifelse=Dat3[col_set] <- ifelse(Dat3[col_set] == "cat", "mammal",
                                 ifelse(Dat3[col_set] == "lizard", "reptile",
                                        ifelse(Dat3[col_set] == "parrot", "bird", NA))),
  look_vec=Dat4[] <- lapply(Dat4, function(i) look[i]),
  times=3L
)

## 1e3 x 1e3
# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#     lapply  40.42905  63.47053  78.03831  86.51201  96.84294 107.17387     3  a 
#     unlist 513.25197 540.55981 656.25420 567.86766 727.75531 887.64297     3   b
# unlist_mat  45.91743  56.51087  68.50595  67.10432  79.80021  92.49611     3  a 
#     ifelse 117.83513 153.23771 366.16708 188.64030 490.33306 792.02581     3  ab
#   look_vec  58.54449  88.40293 112.91165 118.26137 140.09522 161.92908     3  a
```

```
## 1e4 x 1e4
# Unit: seconds
#       expr       min        lq      mean    median         uq        max neval cld
#     lapply  2.427077  3.558234  3.992481  4.689390   4.775183   4.860977     3  a 
#     unlist 73.125989 79.203107 94.027433 85.280225 104.478155 123.676084     3   b
# unlist_mat  4.940254  5.011684  5.576553  5.083114   5.894703   6.706291     3  a 
#     ifelse  9.714553 14.444899 36.176777 19.175244  49.407889  79.640535     3  a 
#   look_vec  8.460969  8.558600  8.784463  8.656230   8.946209   9.236188     3  a
```

```
## 1e5 x 1e3
# Unit: seconds
#       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval cld
#     lapply  2.314427  2.403001  3.270708  2.491575  3.748848   5.006120     3  a 
#     unlist 64.098825 66.850221 81.402676 69.601616 90.054601 110.507586     3   b
# unlist_mat  5.018869  5.060865  5.638499  5.102861  5.948314   6.793767     3  a 
#     ifelse  6.244744 16.488266 39.208119 26.731788 55.689807  84.647825     3  ab
#   look_vec  4.512672  6.434651  7.496267  8.356630  8.988064   9.619498     3  a
```

```
## 1e3 x 1e5
# Unit: seconds
#       expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
#     lapply  52.833019  55.373432  71.308981  57.913845  80.546963 103.180080     3 ab 
#     unlist 164.901805 168.710285 186.454796 172.518765 197.231292 221.943819     3   c
# unlist_mat   3.872551   4.422904   4.695393   4.973257   5.106814   5.240372     3 a  
#     ifelse  72.592437  76.473418 103.930063  80.354399 119.598876 158.843354     3  b 
#   look_vec  56.444824  58.904604  62.677267  61.364383  65.793488  70.222593     3 ab
```

<sup>**Note:** Performed on an *Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz* using `R --vanilla`.</sup>

```
all(sapply(list(Dat2, as.data.frame(Mat), Dat3, Dat4), identical, Dat1))  ## *
# [1] TRUE
## *manipulate the data first outside the benchmark, of course!
```

### Conclusion

Using `lapply` with a lookup matrix appears to be a good choice if the number of columns is rather low/lower than the number of rows. If we have many columns, especially compared to rows, we might benefit from coercing the respective columns of the data frame into a matrix first, which should only take a blink of an eye.

---

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1e4; m <- 1e4
Dat <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c("cat", "lizard", "parrot"), n*m, replace=TRUE), n, m))
Look <- structure(list(pet = c("cat", "lizard", "parrot"), class = c("mammal", "reptile", "bird")),
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
look <- setNames(as.character(Look$class), Look$pet)
col_set <- names(Dat)
system.time(
  Mat <- as.matrix(Dat)
)
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.844   0.318   1.161 
Dat1 <- Dat2 <- Dat3 <- Dat4 <- Dat
```