# Replace Values in Dataframe using a Lookup Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

I want to replace values in the *df* dataframe using the *lookup* dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({
                  'no1':[20,20,40,10,50],
                  'no2':[50,20,10,40,50],
                  'no3':[30,10,50,40,50]
                  })

   no1  no2 no3
0   20  50  30
1   20  20  10
2   40  10  50
3   10  40  40
4   50  50  50

lookup=pd.DataFrame({'label':['A','B','C','D','E'],
                  'id':[10,20,30,40,50]})

    label id
0   A     10
1   B     20
2   C     30
3   D     40
4   E     50
```

Particularly, I'd like to have:

```
   no1  no2 no3
0   B   E   C
1   B   B   A
2   D   A   E
3   A   D   D
4   E   E   E
```

What is the best way doing it using pandas?

P.S.: I found a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636315/replace-values-in-a-dataframe-based-on-lookup-table) herein, but I do not quite follow as it is in R. A Python solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with a dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({
                  'no1':[20,20,40,10,50],
                  'no2':[50,20,10,40,50],
                  'no3':[30,10,50,40,50]
                  })

lookup=pd.DataFrame({'label':['A','B','C','D','E'],
                  'id':[10,20,30,40,50]})

result = df.replace(dict(zip(lookup.id, lookup.label)))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  no1 no2 no3
0   B   E   C
1   B   B   A
2   D   A   E
3   A   D   D
4   E   E   E
```

Comment: Thanks. Excellent solution. I wonder which one to mark as the accepted solution, all answers are great. You guys rock.

Answer (score 5):

You can construct a dictionary and then use [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
d = lookup.set_index('id')['label'].to_dict()  # or d = dict(np.fliplr(lookup.values))
df.iloc[:] = np.vectorize(d.get)(df.values)

print(df)

  no1 no2 no3
0   B   E   C
1   B   B   A
2   D   A   E
3   A   D   D
4   E   E   E
```

Comment: Nice one with numpy vectorize.  Maybe use d = dict(np.fliplr(lookup.values)) to avoid slow set_index?

Comment: Thanks. Excellent solution. I wonder which one to mark as the accepted solution, all answers are great. You guys rock.

Comment: To my taste and limited Python knowledge, Daniel Mesejo's solution seems more understandable. Yet it could be that for example yours to be more efficient! Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: I wish multiple accepted answers were allowed here. Hopefully in future this feature will be available. Cheers

Comment: for a similar task on my moderately powerful laptup, I used `np.vectorize` on a medium sized df (50k rows, 10 columns) and a large lookup table (4 mio rows of name-id pairs), and it worked almost instantaneously. however, on a much larger df it broke: `Unable to allocate 17.8 TiB for an array with shape (3400599, 25) and data type <U57543`. note: this was on **all** columns. going column by column, it works in some instances, on others  with more diverse data structure it doesn't, so I'll have to figure out a way to break down the task - but this answer is the right way imo!

Comment: This one worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1):

First create `Series` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), but it should be slow in large `DataFrame`:

```
s = lookup.set_index('id')['label']
df = df.replace(s)
```

Solutions for `None` or `NaN`s for non matched values with [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) or [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df = df.applymap(s.get)
```

Or:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.map(s))
```

Or:

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = df[c].map(s)
```

---

```
print (df)
  no1 no2 no3
0   B   E   C
1   B   B   A
2   D   A   E
3   A   D   D
4   E   E   E
```

Comment: Thanks. Excellent solutions. I wonder whose to mark as the accepted solution, all answers are great. You guys rock.