# How to replace string values in a column based on a lookup table

Tags: r, string, lookup

I have this df.  I'd like to replace every instance of "1.1", "2.1" "3.2", etc. based on a lookup table.

[image]

Lookup table

[image]

Desired output

[image]

I looked at [Replace values in a dataframe based on lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636315/replace-values-in-a-dataframe-based-on-lookup-table..but) it doesn't solve my problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be `gsubfn`. We match one or more digits with a dot (`[0-9.]+`) as the pattern and in the replacement, pass a `list` of key/value pairs created from the second dataset ('df2').  For the matching pattern with the 'keys', it replace the corresponding 'value' within the string

```
library(gsubfn)
df1$Node <- gsubfn("([0-9.]+)", as.list(setNames(df2$Label,df2$Node)), df1$Node)
df1$Node
#[1] "One one > Two one > Three two" "One two > Two two > Three one" "One one > Two two > Three one" "One two > Two one > Three two"
#[5] "One one > Two two > Three two"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = 1:5, Node = c("1.1 > 2.1 > 3.2", "1.2 > 2.2 > 3.1", "1.1 > 2.2 > 3.1", "1.2 > 2.1 > 3.2", "1.1 > 2.2 > 3.2"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(Label =  c("One one", "One two", "Two one", "Two two", "Three one", "Three two"), Node = c("1.1", "1.2", "2.1", "2.2", "3.1", "3.2"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: That works. Thanks! One question. Why do you  use "([0-9.]+)" as pattern?

Comment: @Ketty Because it is decimal number `0-9` and `.`

Comment: Ah I see...because df1$Node and df2$Node are numbers and `.`. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ketty No problem.  I added some explanation