# How to replace string patterns with some numbers using gsubfn

Tags: r, string, pattern-matching, gsubfn

I have a dataset `df1`.

[image]

I'd like to replace each occurence of "One + one," "Two ; one," etc. with some numbers as shown in the lookup table `df2`.

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Any idea how to do this? This is a follow-up to my original question
[How to replace string values in a column based on a lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56281390/how-to-replace-string-values-in-a-column-based-on-a-lookup-table/56281485?noredirect=1#comment99177685_56281485)

I tried the following but it doesn't work. Thanks in advance!

```
 df1$New <- gsubfn::gsubfn("[A-z]+,;", as.list(setNames(df2$Node,df2$Label)), df1$Node)
```

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = 1:5, Node = c("One + one > Two ; one > Three ; two", "One + two > Two ; two > Three ; one", "One + one > Two ; two > Three ; one", "One + two > Two ; one > Three ; two", "One + one > Two ; two > Three ; two"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(Label =  c("One + one", "One + two", "Two ; one", "Two ; two", "Three ; one", "Three ; two"), Node = c("1.1", "1.2", "2.1", "2.2", "3.1", "3.2"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

UPDATED DATA:

`df1 <- data.frame(ID = 1:5, Node = c("AO Ales + Bitter > Brown and Stout > Premium && Super Premium", 
"Lager > Dry, Premium Strength, Style, Traditional > Mainstream & Value", 
"AO Ales + Bitter > Dry, Premium Strength, Style, Traditional > Mainstream & Value", 
"Lager > Brown and Stout > Dry, Premium Strength, Style, Traditional", 
"AO Ales + Bitter > Dry, Premium Strength, Style, Traditional > Premium && Super Premium"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

`df2 <- data.frame(Label =  c("AO Ales + Bitter",
+                              "Lager",
+                              "Brown and Stout",
+                              "Dry, Premium Strength, Style, Traditional", 
+                              "Mainstream & Value",
+                              "Premium && Super Premium"
+ ), Node = c("1.1", "1.2", "2.1", "2.2", "3.1", "3.2"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Could you share code to reproduce your data, instead of (or in addition to, if you like) screenshots? That makes it much easier in general to help you.

Comment: @Benjamin. Just added. Thanks!

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happened? Did you get an error message, and if so what was it?

Comment: I think the pattern is not right.  You may need `([A-Za-z]+ \\+ [A-Za-z]+)`

Comment: @Benjamin, df1$new is the same as df1$Node -- not what I expect.

Comment: @Ketty here, it replaces `gsubfn::gsubfn("([A-Za-z]+ \\+ [A-Za-z]+)", as.list(setNames(df2$Node,df2$Label)), df1$Node)` based on the key/value pair ie. the part where `One + one` which matches with the second dataset, but if you need to replace the other part, have to create a second keyvalue pair

Comment: @akrun, this pattern doesn't work either. It replaces "One + one" with "1.1", but it doesn't replace "Two ; two" or "Three ; one."

Comment: @Ketty it is because of the match.  I posted an easier solution for this

Comment: You could also use `stringr` and `dplyr`, and you wouldn't even need a regular expression: `df1 <- mutate(df1, New = str_replace_all(New, setNames(df2$Node, df2$Label)))`. Your question specified use of `gsubfn`, or I'd offer this as an answer. ;)

Comment: @Benjamin, thanks so much! Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this more easily

```
library(gsubfn)
library(english)
gsubfn("([a-z]+)", as.list(setNames(1:9, as.character(as.english(1:9)))), 
                tolower(gsub("\\s*[+;]\\s*", ".", df1$Node)))
#[1] "1.1 > 2.1 > 3.2" "1.2 > 2.2 > 3.1" "1.1 > 2.2 > 3.1" 
#[4] "1.2 > 2.1 > 3.2" "1.1 > 2.2 > 3.2"
```

#### Update

Based on the new example, we can do this in `base R`

```
nm1 <- setNames(df2$Node, df2$Label)
sapply(strsplit(df1$Node, " > "), function(x) paste(nm1[x], collapse = " > "))
#[1] "1.1 > 2.1 > 3.2" "1.2 > 2.2 > 3.1" "1.1 > 2.2 > 3.1" 
#[4] "1.2 > 2.1 > 2.2" "1.1 > 2.2 > 3.2"
```

Comment: I updated my question with some real-world data. The ones I posted earlier are just simple examples. In real data, users can put any text as the node label for 1.1. for example "AO Ales + Bitter".

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks so much, everyone!