# Making a new variable in for loop using ifelse(), but the second loop erases first loops accomplishment

Tags: r

stataData =  the orginal data

| country |
| --- |
| "246" |
| "246" |
| "246" |
| "752" |
| "752" |
| "752" |
| "643" |
| "643" |
| "643" |
| "840" |
| "840" |
| "840" |

my goal is to add a new column which get a value of 1 if country is 246 or 752; value 2 if country is 643 or 840. goal stataData looks like -->

| country | area |
| --- | --- |
| "246" | 1 |
| "246" | 1 |
| "246" | 1 |
| "752" | 1 |
| "752" | 1 |
| "752" | 1 |
| "643" | 2 |
| "643" | 2 |
| "643" | 2 |
| "840" | 2 |
| "840" | 2 |
| "840" | 2 |

In this case countries is a list of two data frames: (In real case there can be more data frames in the list and there will be more countries)

```
  countries <- list(data.frame(c("FIN", "SWE"), c("246", "752")), data.frame(c("RUS", "USA"), c("643", "840")
  for(i in length(countries)){
    stataData$alue <- ifelse(stataData$country %in% countries[[i]][,2], i, stataData$country )
  }
```

However this code returns a data frame (stataData) where there is only number for the second set of countries, like this:

| country | area |
| --- | --- |
| "246" | "246" |
| "246" | "246" |
| "246" | "246" |
| "752" | "752" |
| "752" | "752" |
| "752" | "752" |
| "643" | 2 |
| "643" | 2 |
| "643" | 2 |
| "840" | 2 |
| "840" | 2 |
| "840" | 2 |

I have tried using is_empty() but haven't find the way to eliminate the problem. So I'm asking how to solve the problem. In the real case in the stataData there is over 1.5milj observations.

edit. Clarifying the problem.

lets say that I have

```
ifelse(df$x1 %in% delta, i, NA)
```

where delta is an element of a list and i is a number. Is there way to increase the i when delta goes forward.

Cheers!

Comment: ifelse is vectorised, no need for forloops. Something like: `stataData$area <- ifelse(stataData$country %in% c("246", "752"), 1, ifelse(stataData$country %in% c("643", "840"), 2, NA))`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/18012222/680068

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/35636315/680068

Comment: Okey probably I wasn't clear enough. The problem is when the number of groups are unknow, the one who uses the function might want to make 4 country groups but don't want touch the underlying function. So what I tried to ask was, is there anyway to automaticly change the yes part of ifelse(). Lets say that I have ifelse(df$x1==delta, i, NA), where delta and i changes, e.g. delta is a element of the list and i is a number, when delta cahnges, i increases. Hopefully this clarifies a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a lookup table and then perform a `merge`

```
lookup <- data.frame(country = c(246, 752, 643, 840), area = c(1, 1, 2, 2))
result <- merge(stataData, lookup, by = 'country')

#   country area
#1      246    1
#2      246    1
#3      246    1
#4      643    2
#5      643    2
#6      643    2
#7      752    1
#8      752    1
#9      752    1
#10     840    2
#11     840    2
#12     840    2
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
stataData <- data.frame(country = rep(c(246, 752, 643, 840), each = 3))
```