# Changing a value of a dataframe based on value of another dataframe

Tags: r

how do I change a value of a dataframe, based on another dataframe with different column names? I have Table 1 and Table 2, and would like to produce the Desired outcome as stated below.

I would like to change Number column of table 1, if Index of table 1 exists in Alphabet of Table2, without the use of if else as my dataframe is large.

Table 1)

| Index | Number |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 4 |

Table 2)

| Alphabet | Integer |
| --- | --- |
| B | 25 |
| C | 30 |

Desired Output:

| Index | Number |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 25 |
| C | 30 |
| D | 4 |

Comment: What are the criteria? In other words, looking at your desired output that could mean either 1) You  want all in Table 1 and replace the values from Table 2 if higher or 2) You want all from Table 2 and append with those letters from Table 1 not prensent in Table 2. This will give just on this sample the same outcome, but is essential to know.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply.
I would like to change Number column of table 1, if Index of table 1 exists in Alphabet of Table2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace values in a dataframe based on lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636315/replace-values-in-a-dataframe-based-on-lookup-table)

Answer (score 2):

What's the issue with using `ifelse()` on a large dataframe with simple replacement?

```
df1 <- data.frame(Index = LETTERS[1:4], 
                  Number = 1:4)
df2 <- data.frame(Alphabet = c("B", "C"),
                  Integer = c(25, 30))

df1$Number2 <- ifelse(df1$Index %in% df2$Alphabet, df2$Integer, df1$Number)
df1
#>   Index Number Number2
#> 1     A      1       1
#> 2     B      2      30
#> 3     C      3      25
#> 4     D      4       4
```

Perhaps if you are concerned with incorrect indexing when using `ifelse()`, you could use `merge()` like this:

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x = "Index", by.y = "Alphabet", all.x = TRUE)
#>   Index Number Integer
#> 1     A      1      NA
#> 2     B      2      25
#> 3     C      3      30
#> 4     D      4      NA
```