# Function and for loop issue in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

The function I am using is not working properly. The function was to match up a dataset by using codes to multiple columns in another dataset. After matching, it replaces the multiple columns with a description of the code's meaning.

CodeConditionPreg:

| Code | label |
| --- | --- |
| 04 | Renal disease |
| 06 | Anemia |
| 00 | None |
| 18 | Hepatitis B |

Birth_IndicatorsConditions:

| Complications1 | Complications2 | Complications3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06 | 04 | NA |
| 00 | NA | NA |
| 04 | 06 | 18 |

```
CleanConditionPreg <- function(Condition){
  codes <- Condition %>% select(starts_with(c("Complications")))
  labels <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow(Condition), 0))          
  names <- rep(NA, ncol(codes))

# For each column of codes, match corresponding labels and assign new variable names
    for (i in seq(1, ncol(codes))) {
      labels[,i] <- CodeConditionPreg[match(codes[,i], CodeConditionPreg$code),2] 
      names[i] <- paste0("Other_Complications", i-1)  
    }
  
    # Rename first diagnosis as principal, then append new named columns to data frame
    names[1] <- "Complications"
    colnames(labels) <- names
    Condition <- cbind(Condition, labels) 
   
}

Birth_IndicatorsWithConditions <- CleanConditionPreg(Birth_IndicatorsConditions)
```

This gives me this as a printout of blank values but are producing the new columns: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x95Uh.png)
It seems like the function is working, but I dont know what I am missing to put the label into the larger dataset.

I am trying to get it to look like:

| Complications | Other_Complications1 | Other_Complications2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anemia | Renal disease | NA |
| None | NA | NA |
| Renal disease | Anemia | Hepatitis B |

Comment: What language is this, R? Please [edit] to add the tag for it. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], and check out [ask] for tips.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: Any time I see a question with a loop to match data from one table to data from another, my first thought is to see if a join would work. Simpler and much much faster.

Comment: I think this question is pretty much the same -- do the answers here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636315/replace-values-in-a-dataframe-based-on-lookup-table

Comment: @JonSpring Yes, and No. I have other columns in the data set like Date of birth and first and last name that disappear when using 
as.data.frame(lapply(BirthCOnditions, function(x) CodeConditionPreg$label[match(x, CodeConditionPreg$code)]))

Comment: ```library(tidyverse); Birth_IndicatorsConditions %>% rowid_to_column() %>% pivot_longer(-c(rowid, date_of_birth, first, last, etc)) %>% left_join(CodeConditionPreg, by = c("value"= "Code")) %>% select(-value) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "label") %>% select(-rowid)```